# Assigning remainder value to largest value in stacked SSRS bar graph

Tags: reporting-services, stacked-chart

I have a 100% stacked bar graph in SSRS.  Due to the rounding some of the categories does not add up to 100.  In some instances the total would be 99 or 101.

I want to achieve the following:
1. Calculate the total of the stack
2. If the total is greater than 100 then the difference should be deducted from the smallest value in the stack
3. If the total is smaller than 100 then the difference should be added to the largest value in the stack

Is this possible? 
Or what other solution is there to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving this functionality dynamically within the report itself would be very difficult and likely inefficient. I would suggest doing this calculation in the database instead. For example, have your SQL query populate a temporary table, run the logic to update the table, and then return the results to the report dataset.

This depends on the type of database you're using and the permissions you have. But in general, this would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the precision of the results in your data.  If your percentages are at 1 or 2 decimals (100.00%), you are highly unlikely to have enough remainders to run up or down a full integer.  100.02% should still show as 100% when formatted without decimals.